# Android emulator wifi interface returns 'wrong data byte #8 should be 0x8 but was 0xc0' on ping

Tags: android, android-emulator

My internal network is on 192.168.0.0/24.
My dev machine has 192.168.0.42. If I try to ping it from adb shell it returns:

```
PING 192.168.0.42 (192.168.0.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
Warning: time of day goes back (-519778839us), taking countermeasures.
Warning: time of day goes back (-519778317us), taking countermeasures.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.42: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=0.000 ms
wrong data byte #8 should be 0x8 but was 0xc0
#8  c0 a8 0 2a 0 0 5b ca 0 8 0 1 ea 9a 81 5a 42 34 b 0 8 9 a b c d e f 
10 11 12 13
#40 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20 21 22 23
```

`AndroidWifi` is enabled...

If I use a real device everything works fine...

I know that I can reach the host via 10.0.2.2 but the problem is that I use self signed certificates and they need a valid dns-name

`ip address` on the emulator returns

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:00:00:44:55:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.232.2/21 brd 192.168.239.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fec0::6ccf:63a3:3c59:d782/64 scope site temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 86309sec preferred_lft 14309sec
    inet6 fec0::ff:fe44:5566/64 scope site dynamic
       valid_lft 86309sec preferred_lft 14309sec
    inet6 fe80::ff:fe44:5566/64 scope link
```

If I set wlan0 to the static ip address 192.168.0.110 it continuously tries to reconnect the WIFI-Interface????